# Testing for Spring MVC handler mappings

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to test for the existence of Handler Mappings in Spring MVC. This would help me to abstract some custom cases where a certain request needs to be handled by a non-standard handler mapping.

I don't really see an easy way to say: mapping "/*/registration/register/custom", does it exist?

Any ideas?

Marc

Answer (score 0):

easy way to test mapping:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
public class HomeControllerTest extends TestCase{

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(true, checkIfURLExists("http://localhost:8080/test"));
    }


    public static boolean checkIfURLExists(String targetUrl) {
        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn;
        try {
            httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(targetUrl).openConnection();
            httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // Set timeouts in milliseconds
            httpUrlConn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            httpUrlConn.setReadTimeout(30000);

            // Print HTTP status code/message for your information.
            System.out.println("Response Code: " + httpUrlConn.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Response Message: " + httpUrlConn.getResponseMessage());

            return (httpUrlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

From Spring Documentation: 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#unit-testing-spring-mvc

> 9.2.2.2 Spring MVC
>
> The org.springframework.test.web package contains ModelAndViewAssert,
>   which you can use in combination with JUnit 4+, TestNG, and so on for
>   unit tests dealing with Spring MVC ModelAndView objects.
>
> Unit testing Spring MVC Controllers To test your Spring MVC
>   Controllers, use ModelAndViewAssert combined with
>   MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpSession, and so on from the
>   org.springframework.mock.web package.

Comment: That doesn't seem to deliver the required functionality.